# multiple instances of embedded jetty

Tags: java, sockets, networking, jetty, embedded-jetty

I run an embedded jetty from eclipse using maven build configuration (jetty:run). The server starts properly:

```
2011-07-07 13:48:11.915:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTING

[INFO] Started Jetty Server

[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 10 seconds
```

Afterwards, I startup another instance listening to the same port (8080). It started properly as well. How does it possible that several instances simultaneously running and listening to the same port? BTW, my web application works fine and all the requests are going to the first instance, after shutting it down, the requests are following to the second instance.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is the behaviour of the `SelectChannelConnector`, which uses `java.nio` selectors instead of `java.net.Socket`.  I'm not sure how or why two instances are allowed to "listen" to the same port (I'm not even sure if "listen" is the right word to use for `java.nio`).  The behaviour you're seeing is consistent, though - the second `SelectChannelConnector` will start receiving the messages after the first one has stopped.

You can reproduce the "traditional" behaviour by replacing `SelectChannelConnector` with `SocketConnector`.